# add css for IE browser in drupal 7

Tags: html, css, drupal

I have create a path in template.php file and included in info file.In my source code I have the path which I want to use.But the css file is not shown in network and cleared drupal chache in perfomance.still css not included.What I have to do

template.php

```
function phoenix_responsive_theme_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
 drupal_add_css(
drupal_get_path('theme', 'phoenix_responsive_theme') . '/css/ie_style.css',
array(
  'group' => CSS_THEME,
  'browsers' => array(
    'IE' => TRUE,
    '!IE' => FALSE,
   ),
   'weight' => 999,
  'every_page' => TRUE,
 )
 );
}
function phoenix_responsive_theme_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$vars) {
// Add conditional stylesheets for IE.
drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'phoenix_responsive_theme') . '/css/ie_style.css',
array(
  'group' => CSS_THEME,
  'browsers' => array(
    'IE' => TRUE,
    '!IE' => FALSE,
  ),
  'weight' => 999,
  'every_page' => TRUE,
)
);
}
```

path seen in html source code

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css" media="all">
 @import url("http://localhost/test/themes/phoenix_responsive_theme/css/ie_style.css?osct7n");
```

Comment: Add tag `php` to the question. It's _php drupal_ topic question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one .

Reference : [Adding browser-specific style sheets](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/advanced/adding-browser-specific-style-sheets)

```
 function yourthemename_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
   drupal_add_css(
     path_to_theme() . '/fix-ie.css', 
     array('weight' => CSS_THEME, 
           'browsers' => array('IE' => 'lt IE 7', '!IE' => FALSE), 
           'preprocess' => FALSE
     ));
    }
```